# Cannot instantiate abstract class with multiple inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I am getting the compiler error `C2259` when instantiating a class that inherits from other classes, which having abstract methods.

The inheritance scheme is a little bit weird and opaque but I need to do it in this way due to some restrictions of the problem.

The inheritance scheme is as follow:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum Animal { CAT, DOG };
    enum Color { RED, GREEN };
    enum Food { MEAT, FISH };

protected:
    virtual Animal animal() const = 0;
    virtual Color color() const = 0;
    virtual Food food() const = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
Animal animal() const { return CAT; }
};

class C: public A
{
Color color() const { return GREEN; }
};

class D: public A
{
Food food() const { return FISH; }
};
```

And then I declare a class with multiple inheritance like this:

```
class E : public B, public C, public D
{
};
```

Here, when I try to instantiate the class `E` I am getting the compiler error `C2259`:

```
error C2259: 'E': cannot instantiate abstract class
note: due to following members:
note: 'A::Color A::color(void) const': is abstract
note: see declaration of 'A::color'
note: 'A::Food A::food(void) const': is abstract
note: see declaration of 'A::food'
note: 'A::Animal A::animal(void) const': is abstract
note: see declaration of 'A::animal'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Javier

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also where is the virtual destructor?

Comment: Class `E` has multiple instances of `A` in it, and not all `A` methods are overridden by all instances.  For this kind of situation, you need to use `virtual` inheritance instead of `public` inheritance. Or else break up `A` into smaller pieces.

Comment: The only purpose all those `...` serve is to prevent people from copy-pasting and compiling your code. `E` has 3 distinct copies of `A`, none of which implement all the pure virtual functions. You want to use `virtual` inheritance instead.

Comment: All sub-classes have the virtual destructor. I've tried to simplify a lot the code, only writing the inheritance scheme and the declaration of the virtual methods

Comment: It's not the subclasses that need to have the virtual destructor, it's the original parent class `A`.

Comment: You are gods guys! Thank you very much. The `...` are because the class is huge and I cannot paste all the code...

Comment: please include the error message in the question. C2259 only has a meaning for the specific compiler you are using, in principle it could even be that two compilers use the same number for two different errors

Comment: The request isn't to paste _all_ the code, it's to paste _compilable_ code sufficient to reproduce the problem. Making people edit your code before they can test something is just increasing the effort required to help.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3 different `A` objects inside `E`, you forgot to tag the inheritance as virtual so that the same `A` object is used:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum Animal { CAT, DOG };
    enum Color { RED, GREEN };
    enum Food { MEAT, FISH };

    virtual ~A(){}

protected:
    virtual Animal animal() const = 0;
    virtual Color color() const = 0;
    virtual Food food() const = 0;
};

class B: public virtual A
{
Animal animal() const override { return CAT; }
};

class C: public virtual A
{
Color color() const override { return GREEN; }
};

class D: public virtual A
{
Food food() const override { return FISH; }
};

class E : public B, public C, public D
{
};

int main()
{
    E e;
}
```

Comment: You are a god! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I wouldn't go that far :p

Comment: FWIW, this is the canonical example of virtual inheritance - and is also often thought to suggest a bad initial design. It's certainly a code smell. If you _need_ this design though, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Matthieu, one thing I learned from living through the 80s was [when someone asks if you are a god, you say yes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6LD6ITN2dk) I think this case is a close duplicate.